# Is there a way to call a function on a page from a chrome extension and get the output?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Say I have a webpage like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function getData() {
            return 1
        }
        </script>
    <!head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello!</p>
    <!body>
<!html>
```

and for some reason I want to call `getData()` from a chrome extension and get the result from the function, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You'll need to inject a script inside the `DOM`. Extensions share the same DOM as the host, but different JS contexts (so you have a sandbox).

To do this you'll need to add a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) and then inject a JS script (either via DOM api that load an existing script or inlining your code).

From the injected script you'll be able to call `window.getData` for instance and then you can use `window.postMessage` to communicate with your extension back.

Comment: needs more detail